# List Object Not Callable on multiple functions used on single Element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving a competitive programming question, but this error keeps popping up. Here is my code:

```
   import math
    def palcheck(check,l):
    i=-1
    for x in range(0,l):
        if(check[x]!=check[i]):
            return False
        i=i-1
    return True


def mirror(s,length):
    pivot=math.floor(length/2)
    if length%2 == 0:
        i=length-1
        j=0
        while j <= pivot:
            s[i]=s[j]
            j=j+1
            i=i-1
    else:
        i=length-1
        j=0
        while j <= pivot-1:
            s[i]=s[j]
            j=j+1
            i=i-1


def nextpal(s):
temp=list(s)
l=len(s)
if not palcheck(s,l):
    mirror(temp,l)
n1=int(s)
n2=int(''.join(temp))
i=math.floor(l/2)
j=math.ceil(l/2)
if(n1>n2):
    while n1>n2:
        if i==0:
            break
        if i==j:
            temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])+1)
        else:
            temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])+1)
            temp[j]=str(int(temp[j])+1)
        if temp[i] == 9 and temp[j] == 9:
            i=i-1
            j=j+1
        n2=int(''.join(temp))

else:
    i=math.floor(l/2)
    j=math.ceil(l/2)
    while n1<n2:
        if i==0:
            break
        if i==j:
            temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])-1)
        else:
            temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])-1)
            temp[j]=str(int(temp[j])-1)
        if temp[i] == 0 and temp[j] == 0:
            i=i-1
            j=j+1
        n2=int(''.join(temp))

    if i==j:
        temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])+1)
        n2=int(''.join(temp))
    else:
        temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])+1)
        temp[j]=str(int(temp[j])+1)
        n2=int(''.join(temp))

if i == 0:
    print(n2+2)

t=int(input())
str=[]
for x in range(0,t):
    str.append(input())
for x in str:
    nextpal(x)
```

And, here is the error:

> File "PALIN.py", line 73, in nextpal
>   **temp[i]=str(int(temp[i])+1)**
>   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I can't figure out why, since I'm not using the list object temp to call a function which was a common error in questions asked with the same title

For insight in using the number present in the form of a character, at the given index, converting to an integer, incrementing it, and changing it back to a character.

Comment: `str=[]` is the culprit. `str` is a list but you do `str(int(temp[i])+1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name `str` for your lists. Don't forget that `str` is a builtin function.

```
>>> str = 1
>>> str(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    str(4)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> str
1
```

Rename your list `str` to another name because you also need to convert numbers into string.
Look at the end of your code. Your last part of code can be like:

```
mylist=[]
for x in range(0,t):
    mylist.append(input())
for x in mylist:
    nextpal(x)
```

To remove your confusion, Here is another piece of code:

```
>>> def abc(string):
    print(string)

>>> str = 1
>>> abc(str)
1
>>>
```

You can use the outside variables in the function but you can't use variables of the function outside the function.

Comment: My question is arent local variable names declared in a function local to that function only. So str was decalred in main but in nextpal() the interpreter should consider it as a function right?

Comment: @Hunting_Party10 Check the edit. `str` becomes global in a way.

Answer (score 3):

You have a list named `str`, but also want to call a function named `str`.

Change the name of your list to avoid that name collision.

Comment: But isn't str local to the main function? So how is it causing a collision in name

Comment: You define `str` outside your functions (`str=[]` at the 5th line from the end). Unless of course your indentation is just that badly off, in which case you need to fix that before any diagnosis can take place.

Comment: No the indentation was correct,my question is arent variable names declared in any functions local to that function only So str was decalred in main but in nextpal() the interpreter should consider it as a function right?

Comment: @Hunting_Party10: Your `str` is not defined "in main", as there's no main function to speak of. It's global to your module. Functions within your module will see your list, rather than the function, when they reach for `str`. If you really want, you could resolve the issue by *putting* your code in a `main` function and then calling it. But frankly, it'd be better to just use a name other than `str` for your list.